# ChildBrowser not showing webpage in cordova 2.0/phonegap 1.9

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-2.0.0, childbrowser

hi im trying to use `childbrowser` to login in facebook and get response back to the application in `cordova 2.0`.

i Install and configure successfully with no error. and console also shows me message like : "Opening Url **** " but browser wont appear.

so how can i solve this issue in `cordova 2.0` phonegap application.

any help appreciable.Milan Mendpara

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i solved it by adding "ChildBrowser" as key/value under plugin section of Cordova.plist file  and also tried :

http://blog.digitalbackcountry.com/2012/03/installing-the-childbrowser-plugin-for-ios-with-phonegapcordova-1-5/